# Ways of verifying someones identity on website?

Tags: verification, email-verification

We're running a directoy website where users can claim listings we have pre-populuated.
As we want to each listing have it's rightful owner, we are trying to figure out a way how can we verify that the Person who claimed a certain business or location is actually person of authority of that business?

Not all businesses have websites so we could authenticate by sending an email matching the business domain, phone number verification is also not an option as owning a phone number doesn't proves anything, I think.

We would love to have this process somehow automated, but we have no experience or ideas how to make this work.

Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: You might want to have a look at [Trulioo's EmbedID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47986439/how-to-implement-some-type-of-identity-verification-in-applications/55530092#55530092)

Answer (score 0):

The users need to register with you. They send you enough information to verify that they are who they say they are, eg, passport, driver's licence, credit card statements, electricity bills with address etc. You can then verify that this information is correct. In particular, their physical address must be verified.

You then mail a letter with a code that you choose to their physical address. When they have received it, send a link to their email address. The link is to a page where they must enter the code you mailed to them. They can then register with a userid and password of their choice. This only needs to be done once. After that, they can identify themselves with the userid and password they chose.

This technique relies on the fact that you can verify someone's physical address. Anyone can call you and claim to be someone else but the credit card company and the electricity company know their customer's correct address. It is possible to use someone else's credit card number and provide a different address but the credit card company will be able to tell you if the physical address they gave you is wrong.