# How to implement some type of identity verification in applications

Tags: java, android

I have plans for a development of an application for phones under the programming language of `java`.

It's going to have users who can create an account and use the application. The thing is, I want to implement some type of identity verification to make sure that there will be no chance of any potential foul play or crimes while using this app.

I am unsure of where to start or how to implement this idea into an application. If anyone has any advice on where I can start I would appreciate it very much.

I apologize if this is not the correct `location` for this type of question or if it's unclear as I am unsure of how to approach this situation.

Comment: Are you trying to say that you want to make sure that the registered email id is real or fake right??

Comment: you can use face recognition for this.Take user's image when logged in and then match it with system.

Comment: Send two OTP,  1) on Email 2) and other otp on Text message.. if user enters both otp correct inside App, let the user sign in.

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate with the [Trulioo API](https://www.trulioo.com/developers/identity-verification/) and instantly verify over five billion individuals and 250 million organizations. Although you can use the API with various ways (e.g., [Java](https://github.com/Trulioo/sdk-java-v1), C# etc.), there are a couple of quick-start projects that make integration easy.

Here's an example using node package manager (npm), you can run `npm i trulioo` to install [the EmbedID component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/trulioo-react).

Install [trulioo-react](https://github.com/Trulioo/trulioo-react):

`npm install trulioo-react`

Then in your jsx:

```
import EmbedID from 'trulioo-react/EmbedID'

const handleResponse = (e) => {
    // handle verification submission result here ...
}

<EmbedID url='URL' handleResponse={handleResponse} />
```

`handleResponse` is the callback from the vendor, here's [more info of what's](https://developer.trulioo.com/docs/identity-verification-step-6-verify) the response structure about.

To avoid [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) issues, you will need a backend server; you can either build your own or use [trulioo-react-sample-app](https://github.com/Trulioo/trulioo-react-sample-app):

```
TRULIOO_BASE_URL=
TRULIOO_USERNAME=
TRULIOO_PASSWORD=
TRULIOO_PORT=
SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM=
PRIVATE_KEY_FILE_PATH=
```

Simply run the following command in your cmd/terminal and enjoy the ride.

```
# install the libraries needed
npm i
# start the server
npm start
```

[image]

---

Disclaimer: I work for Trulioo and I am the author of `trulioo-react` and `trulioo-react-sample-app` projects.